# Path variable not recognized in Android Studio (ndk-build command is not recognized)

Tags: macos, path, android-ndk, gradle, android-studio

I have an Android Studio project which won't recognize the PATH variable set for ndk-build.

If I run `ndk-build` from Terminal I get:

```
stpns-MacBook-Pro:~ stepanboltalin$ ndk-build
  Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
  Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
  /usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r10b/build/core/build-local.mk:148: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

But if I try to compile project in Android Studio, I get error at 'ndk-build' commmandLine (below is the excerpt from build.gradle:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {

 # some stuff... 

    if (ant.properties.os == 'windows') {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd'
    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build'
    }


}
```

Now if I add the absolute path everything works fine:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {

 # some stuff... 

    if (ant.properties.os == 'windows') {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd'
    } else {
        commandLine '/usr/local/opt/ndk-build'
    }


}
```

Although the problem is seemingly solved, having build.gradle like that is sub-optimal for development. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you add `/use/local/opt/ndk` to PATH? It should be `~/.profile`

Comment: Yeah I tried .bash_profile and .profile

Comment: .bash_profile is no good because you probably don't run your AS from command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the path to your NDK in the local.properties file of the root project:

```
ndk.dir=/opt/android/ndk
```

Then replace the invocation of ndk-build like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
localProperties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def ndkDir = localProperties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
def ndkBuildPrefix = ndkDir != null ? ndkDir + '/' : '';

if (ant.properties.os == 'windows') {
    commandLine ndkBuildPrefix + 'ndk-build.cmd'
} else {
    commandLine ndkBuildPrefix + 'ndk-build'
}
```

Comment: Hi @Laszio kustra I set ndk.dir=/opt/android/ndk . But I unbale to understand where I can put your below code. Please let me know.

Comment: Create a new Exec type task in build.gradle and use the code above in its body. The task's name can be anything.